# troubles with inner join

Tags: sql

I've got tables

```
Manga
idmanga idgenre idauthor title

Author
idauthor name surname

Genre
idgenre genre
```

I want to create table with fields title,genre,name,surname

```
select * from Manga
      inner join Author on Manga.idauthor=Author.idauthor
      inner join Genre on Manga.idgenre=Genre.idgenre
```

With such query I've got all columns from all table. How to exclude not needed columns?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of writing `SELECT *` just list the columns that you want. It also helps to give your tables aliases:

```
select m.title, g.genre, a.name, a.surname 
from Manga m
inner join Author a on m.idauthor=a.idauthor
inner join Genre  g on m.idgenre=g.idgenre
```

Comment: This is the most complete answer I have seen in the last two minutes :-)

Comment: It won't work due to unknown alias `g`. I believe you did a typo, the same table alias for both `Author` and `Genre` tables == `a`

Answer (score 2):

Use table aliases to specify from which table you need a specific column:

```
SELECT m.title, g.genre, a.name, a.surname
FROM Manga m
INNER JOIN Author a on m.idauthor = a.idauthor
INNER JOIN Genre g on m.idgenre = g.idgenre
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't exclude unneeded columns, only include needed columns:

```
select Manga.title, Genre.genre, Author.name, Author.surname from Manga
      inner join Author on Manga.idauthor=Author.idauthor
      inner join Genre on Manga.idgenre=Genre.idgenre
```